# Covering string by palindromes

Tags: ds.algorithms, dynamic-programming, string-matching, covering-problems

Given a string $w=\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots\sigma_n$, a *palindrome cover* is a sequence $p_1p_2\cdots p_m$ of words $p_i$ such that $p_1p_2\cdots p_m = w$ and such that each $p_i$ is a palindrome.

> How hard is it to find the size minimal palindrome cover? (this seems doable by dynamic programming, but I'm not sure it works).
>
> Does the problem become harder if given as input is also a bound $b$ on each palindrome length?

Consider the simple greedy algorithm, which always takes the longest palindrome which starts at the current location. For example, if $w=1213312$, then it'll output $(121)\cdot(33)\cdot(1)\cdot(2)$, while the optimal cover is $(1)\cdot(213312)$.

> Does the greedy algorithm provide 2-approximation for the problem?

Answer (score 9):

This problem is called *minimum palindromic factorization* and this problem can be solved in $O(n \log n)$ time, see for example:

[A subquadratic algorithm for minimum palindrome factorization](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jda.2014.08.001) by Fici *et al*

[EERTREE: An Efficient Data Structure for Processing Palindromes in Strings](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04862) by Rubinchik and Shur.